# Switching control in tabs in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

While doing automation for my Web page through selenium,when i try to click on a button called "Learn More" it opens a page in a new tab and automatically closes the old tab.(This is a specific case for IE). The main problem is that i am not able to click on the link present in the new tab, the control is not getting switched to the new tab.

I tried all the possibilities of switching windows and switching tabs , but both has not helped me.

And as a result I end up with "No Such Window Exception."

Please help.

Comment: Post your code but odds are you are not switching to the new window

Comment: Have you implemented something like this yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614188/switch-between-two-browser-windows-using-selenium-webdriver