# Selenium Python, New Page

Tags: python, selenium, switch-statement

**My main Question:
How do I switch pages?**

I did some things on a page and than switch to another one,
how do I update the driver to be the current page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/handle-multiple-window-in-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614188/switch-between-two-browser-windows-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 2):

With `.get(url)`, just like you got to the first page.

Comment: But isnt my url always changing because its a dynamic page? or it doesnt work that way?

Comment: Your current url might change, but it has nothing to do with going to another url.